# How to combine two QUERY results into one column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have the following `QUERY`

```
=query(XX!A2:A;" select A where A>'50' ")
```

and

```
=query(YY!A2:A;" select A where A>'50' ")
```

how do I combine these two data sources so I don't have to have two separate columns they process data to?

- best would be if the 1st row from `XX` is followed by the 1st row of `YY`, 2nd row followed by 2nd row... and so on
- If the above option is not easily possible, it is OK for one query to be followed by the second one (if I expect correctly that the start of the second will be moved with newly added data into the first one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most easier is to do:

```
={QUERY(XX!A2:A; "select A where A>'50'");
  QUERY(YY!A2:A; "select A where A>'50'")}
```

```
={QUERY(XX!A2:A; "select A where A is not null");
  QUERY(YY!A2:A; "select A where A is not null")}
```

to zip 2 queries you can do:

```
=QUERY({{ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(QUERY(XX!A2:A; 
 "select A where A is not null")))))\QUERY(XX!A2:A; 
 "select A where A is not null")};
        {ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(QUERY(YY!A2:A; 
 "select A where A is not null")))))\QUERY(YY!A2:A; 
 "select A where A is not null")}}; 
 "select Col2 order by Col1 asc")
```

[image]

Comment: This results in error: `Function 2 parameter ARRAY_ROW has unexpected row dimension. Expected size: 545. real size: 413.`

Comment: are these two queries from the same sheet?

Comment: yes. But in the end I might not need that >50 functionality so basically I just need to combine two lists of IDs from those two sheets into one bigger list that automatically expands once I add new IDs in any of those two sheets

Comment: can you share a copy of that sheet?

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18CShoZzNGAbiRoeK4BboBKVn5RAxmTM-Mxsau2Chxxw)