# How do I get a list of all values in the same column across multiple spreadsheets within the same Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrays

I have a Google sheet that has multiple spreadsheets, let's say `Sheet1`, `Sheet2` and `Sheet3`. In all of those spreadsheets, column `H` is a particular field of which I want all the values with blanks filtered out.

I'm not sure where to begin with this, I've tried `union`ing all the columns into one in another sheet and then filtering all of them but can't get the union to work.

End result would ideally be a single list of all the values from 
`Sheet1.colH`, `Sheet2.colH`, and `Sheet3.colH`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine two QUERY results into one column](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/125791/how-to-combine-two-query-results-into-one-column)

Comment: Use the second suggestion by @user0. `select A where A is not null`; just switch your answer to "select H where H is not null", and include all three sheets . A ready made answer that you could have googled in just a few moment.

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: No need to get snarky. Like I said, I tried searching and wasn't aware of the ability to use queries like that or the array function.

Comment: I'm sorry if you thought I was being "snarky". I wasn't. There'd been no response from you for a few days and it was a genuine request to find out how you were going - whether you've resolved your problem or whether you still needed help.

Answer (score 0):

With an `array` + `filter` :

```
=FILTER(
{Sheet1!H:H;Sheet2!H:H;Sheet3!H:H}
,{Sheet1!H:H;Sheet2!H:H;Sheet3!H:H}<>""
)
```

You can add as many sheet as you want in the array :

```
{Sheet1!H:H;Sheet2!H:H;Sheet3!H:H;Sheet4!H:H;Sheet5!H:H [...]}
```

If you have spaces in the tab names, add a single quote like this :

```
 'Sheet with spaces'!h:h
```

---

With a `query()`, same idea :

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!H:H;Sheet2!H:H},"SELECT Col1 where Col1 is not null",-1)
```